Orbeon Forms: How to add an Icon to a text field
How can you add an icon next to a text field similar to telephone number field in the image below.
We would like to add other images, such as an email icon, to the left-hand side of text boxes.
I tried using the content/before option is CSS, but that seems to work on the textbox label.
Many thanks in advance
PeteA


For number fields, you can define your own prefix and suffix, with the intended purpose of allowing you to specify a unit or currency (such as £ or GBP), and you could even use an emoji.
Unfortunately, you cannot do this for an email field, or more generally for a text field. This isn't something that can be achieved purely with CSS, as it requires additional markup (as illustrated below), at least for the default Bootstrap layout used for other controls. For email fields, one might imagine that adding an email icon should be a built-in feature, to be consistent with how phone number fields are handled.


It would be nice to add our own icons to the start of any field, possibly using awesome font icons.
So fields like name, address, phone, email, priority, etc.
I see that you can enter "fa fa-phone" in the Custom CSS Classes field within a control, but this looks awful.
And you can also add an icon to the end of the label in style via:
         .icon-email:before {font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; content: "\2709"; display: inline-block; padding-right: 3px; vertical-align: middle; font-weight:900;}

This option looks better, but its not to the left of the control.

Could you explain your comment "as it requires additional markup" please.

@PeteAtkin I updated my answer above to include an illustration of the markup that needs to be added to the HTML served to the browser. This clarifies that the task cannot be accomplished solely with CSS. I agree, having an icon picker would be a great feature; I created an RFE #6654 for it.
